# angular how to create a csproj file for existing project

Tags: angular, csproj

I used the angular cli (version 12) to create an angular project.  However, there is no csproj file.  Without losing any of the current files, is there a way to create the csproj?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need a C# project file for an angular CLI project?

Comment: The project folder contains to parts: an API that is C# dotnet core (the backend) and another folder (client) is the Angular front-end.  Make sense?  :-)

Comment: Okay, I get it: CSProj mean it is a C# project, but my real problem is I can't open it in Visual Studio to work on it.  I HAVE to use VSCode, which very buggy.  I've been trying to use Rider, which I don't know very well and I can't get it to recognize it as an Angular folder.

Answer (score 3):

My sincere apologies... I asked the wrong question.  I was trying to add an angular project to an existing C# solution.
THE ANSWER is (from a stackoverflow answer user 3834142)

1. Create a blank solution. (which I didn't need to do)
2. Open solution in VS2019
3. Right mouse click on the Solution
4. Click Add
5. Click existing **website**
6. Browse to the path of the existing angular project and select the folder.

Comment: Thank you.  I wish there was a way to convert it to a cs.proj.  But this will let me save my settings and workspace for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to deploy this site to Azure and your angular app uses routing then your routing will be broken:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable
```

I am struggling with this now. When you add this project as an 'Existing Website' in Visual Studio it will work locally but will not work when deployed to the Azure cloud (assuming you are using Windows Azure AppServices)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31248933)